# handle banners in index page laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a shop project in Laravel.
In my index page i have some banners :

*4 banners in 1 row*
[image: Banner 1]
*2 banners in 1 row*
[image: Banner 2]
*1 banner in 1 row*
[image: Banner 3]

as you can see, i have some banners in different places, i don't know how can i handle banners in admin panel and show in index page, The only way that came to my mind is that make controller and model for each banner, but i think it's not normal way.

can you guide me how can i do this in Laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

How about making a controller name BannerController, under the same form have 3 sections  like 1 for big banner, 2 for medium and 4 for small. Save them in the BannerController and then return to the view, that should work instead of making different controllers for every banner

Comment: what about model and migration ?

Comment: make 1 model name it banner, and make 3 tables in that migration for small medium and large

Comment: in this case, can i edit or delete each banner ? or i can just delete or edit 1 section ? for example i want to edit 4 small banner, can i edit  each 4 small banner or i can just delete all 4 small banner ?

Comment: For example you uploaded 4 small banners, each banner will have a unique id. Ofcourse  you can delete one if you want to.